# Eclipselink IDE support

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, eclipselink

Currently I am using `Eclipselink` with lazy weaving on, powered by `eclipselink-staticweave-maven-plugin` and it is very unproductive as after each code change IDE shows following kind of error:

`Error:(52, 8) java: cannot access org.eclipse.persistence.internal.weaving.PersistenceWeaved
  class file for org.eclipse.persistence.internal.weaving.PersistenceWeaved not found`

Because of this thing I cannot run test or application from IDE, only from maven.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: How do you launch the application? Do you use IDE run/debug configuration? Could you elaborate what does `eclipselink-staticweave-maven-plugin` specifically/additionally to build/run the application? E.g. you can add some specific Maven goal in 'Before launch' section in IDE [Run/Debug Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configurations-dialog.html): e.g. to generate some code before IDE's Make step.

Comment: Did you ever solve this @noobsaibot? I'm seeing it today with EclipseLink 2.6.3. A complicating factor for me may be that my persistence unit is defined at EAR level and all the persistent classes are in the EJB jar.

Comment: @nclark we just moved to hibernate implementation